# Deploy script from SVN to GitHub

Tags: git, svn, github, deployment

I am moving a site from SVN to Git (testing on GitHub). I started by exporting the SVN repo and turning it into a local git repo, then uploaded that repo to GitHub.

What's next is to modify the deployment script so that this particular site uses Git/GitHub, no longer SVN. There are a number of sites on the server that use this deploy script, all of which were using SVN. All but one need to still use SVN.

I was wondering if it might be suggested that I remove anything involving this site from the script, and create a new git-specific deploy script which can be only used for this specific domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to you, indeed, to remove your site-with-git from your svn deploy script and put it in a new deploy script for git, just to have clean scripts. You might then want to call both scripts in another one (deploy-all.sh or whatever) to deploy at the same time if needed. This also ensures that the old SVN repo of your site-with-git won't be deployed by mistake if it's kept somewhere.

To deploy with git, there are lots of tutorials, (see [Deploying with Git/Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619440/deploying-with-git-github) for example), 
depending on your case.

You might need a continuous integration system, or a local copy of the repo on a deploy server that you rsync, or pulling directly from the webserver, or pushing to the webserver with a hook... Lots of options!

Good luck !

Comment: That sounds good. I started the process of removing the old stuff from the existing deploy script. Now I am working on creating a new script for Git/GitHub. Thank you!