# How can I detect when my github repository is pushed to?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github

Have a website hosted on Amazon Web Services and I want to run a bash script to automatically build my github project when changes are pushed to the repository. How can my aws linux server detect when my repository is pushed to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deploying with Git/Github](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619440/deploying-with-git-github)

Comment: Not a duplicate. That is unrelated to my problem as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GitHub's Webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/):

> Every GitHub repository has the option to communicate with a web server whenever the repository is pushed to. These “webhooks” can be used to update an external issue tracker, trigger CI builds, update a backup mirror, or even deploy to your production server.

The [`github-services` project](https://github.com/github/github-services) supports a [large number of popular services](https://github.com/github/github-services/tree/master/lib/services) out of the box.

Alternatively, you can use Webhooks yourself to configure [an HTTP message](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#payloads) to be sent to an arbitrary endpoint when a given [event](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#events) occurs. You would need to configure a service that listens for and responds to GitHub's message on your endpoint.

Comment: Same idea, but missing the listener part.

Comment: Thanks @VonC, I've updated my answer to clarify that the "arbitrary endpoint" must be configured to listen for and respond to GitHub's message.

Comment: I set my webhook to "http://example.com:4444" and I try to listen for it with "nc -l 4444 > filename.out" but I'm not getting anything. Can I only post to a webpage and if so, how can I trigger a bash script with this?

Comment: @SteveDeFacto, you should be able to listen using any tool that understands HTTP, though you'll need to make sure that your endpoint is exposed to GitHub. Their example [uses a tool called `ngrok`](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/configuring/). You may also want to browse [their Testing Webooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/testing/) page, which explains how you can view "recent deliveries".

Answer (score 1):

You can [register a webhook on your GitHub repo](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) in order to [trigger a message](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#payloads) to your aws server.
But, as mentioned in "[Sync the local code to Amazon server through GitHub webhook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20075753/6309)", that means you have a listener on that AWS server which would listen to such a message.